# How do you get a table to be 100% height of the window

Tags: html, html-table

I need your help,

The problem that I am having is that my table does not conform to 100% height of my window. How can the HTML coding below be amended to accommodate this change?

```
<table style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: solid 1px black;">
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; padding: 5px; position: relative;">
            <p style="display: inline-block; width:100%; background: #ccc; vertical-align: middle;">
                Title Text
           </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Expected outcome is:

[image]

Comment: You want center it vertically or expand the border to 100% height?

Comment: That is correct Rafael!

Comment: I did not understand what you want. Do you want both things (center and expand)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also change `height:100%;` to `height:100vh;` Check out this [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1yt01wn2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Add to your CSS following code:

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
}
```

It's important to expand the html and body first.

After that you can make a `<table style="height:100%">` like in the [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o9h8bojc/)